# Django: Format dates according to settings.LANGUAGE_CODE in code (e.g. messages)

Tags: python, django

In my Django 4.2 app's `settings.py` I have

```
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "de-CH"

TIME_ZONE = "CET"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

which works in templates, e.g. `{{ training.date | date:"l, j. M." }}` is displayed as `Sonntag, 11. Jun.`.

However, if I use `strftime` in the code, e.g.

```
self.success_message = (
    f"Eingeschrieben für <b>{self.date.strftime('%A')}</b>, "
    f"den {self.date.strftime('%d. %B %Y')}.".replace(" 0", " ")
)
```

I end up with `Eingeschrieben für Thursday, den 15. June 2023.`.

How do I get get date strings according to `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE` from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`format_date` would be great here, it get a string representation of a date according to the current locale

first we import it `from django.utils import formats` then change your code like that

```
self.success_message = (
    f"Eingeschrieben für <b>{formats.date_format(self.date, 'l')}</b>, "
    f"den {formats.date_format(self.date, 'j. F Y')}.".replace(" 0", " ")
)
```

Comment: That easy, thanks a lot! `USE_L10N` seems not necessary and is deprecated 